# Использование Firebird в Laravel, проблема с верхним регистром имен полей

Tags: laravel, firebird

При разработке вебприложения использую firebird 2.5, для этого установил  расширение sim1984,  все работает,  но возникают проблемы с запросами,  laravel имена полей таблиц пишет  в нижнем регистре,  а firebird в верхнем,  в итоге появляются ошибки.  Причем сразу при работе с системой аутентификации.  Firebird 2.5. Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Какие именно ошибки?

Comment: По умолчанию атрибуты модели в laravel пишутся с маленькой буквы,  если Вы используете firebird в этом случае,  то сразу получите ошибку SQL запроса,  выведется сообщение о том что в таблице нет такого поля,  да и имя таблицы надо в модели указывать в верхнем регистре.

Comment: В Firebird имена таблиц, столбцов и прочего, соответствующие стандарту - не чувствительны к регистру. Регистрозависимость появляется только если имя поля заключено в двойные кавычки, а это необходимо только если имя поле содержит недопустимые символы или совпадает с зарезервированным словом.

Answer (score 0):

Если фреймворк принудительно пишет имена столбцов в нижнем регистре в кавычках, а вы хотите создавать объекты БД вручную сами, а не через фреймворк, то нужно указывать имена таблиц и столбцов в нижнем регистре в двойных кавычках.

Примеры можно посмотреть в статье про sim1984 https://habr.com/ru/post/312874/